# How to return specific elements using Iterator

Tags: java

I've got this kind of iterator. But I want to return only specific element in next() method. In my case, I want to return the object that is the instance of `BagCoffee`

```
@Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<E>(){
            private Node<E> current = head;


            @Override
            public boolean hasNext()  {
                return current != null;             
            }
            @Override
            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();  
            }
            @Override
            public E next() {
                Coffee value = null;
                if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
                if(!(current.value instanceof BagCoffee)) {
                        if(!hasNext()) {
                            current = current.next;
                            return next();
                        } else {
                            //Stop executing method?
                        }

                } else {
                    value = current.value;
                    current = current.next;
                }


                return (E) value;
            }
        };
    }
```

The following code will print what I need and then it will print NullPointerException as it continues to iterate even if hasNext() returns false

```
for(Coffee coff: mySet3) {
            System.out.println("\n");
            coff.sayType();
        }
```

The problem is that I cannot stop method if there are no elements next.

```
if(!hasNext()) {
    current = current.next;
    return next();
} else {
    //Stop executing method
}
```

What's the proper way to make iterator return specific elements and stop method running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you are incorrectly managing the state of your iterator: the value of `current` should not contain anything else than a `BagCoffee`.
If it does, you can't guarantee that the `hasNext()` contract method is respected because it could return `true` even though there are no `BagCoffee` available next.

So you should ensure the correctness of this state at two different time of the life of you object by:

1. Correctly computing the first value of `current` so that it is either a `BagCoffee` or null.
2. Correctly computing the next value of `current` so that it is either a `BagCoffee` or null.

Then you can eventually refactor to avoid duplicated code.

Comment: Made hasNext() method check if current is not null then it checks if it is a BagCoffee and if it is, then current = current.next and invokes hasNext() method again, otherwise returns true.
Works fine, thanks for a clue.